# In App Purchases where I can get the token?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

On official page https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get

the following HTTP request suppose to be send https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token

As last parameter we need to send token. It says *The token provided to the user's device when the subscription was purchased.*

But how I can get it since there is no returned object after the subscription was done? Or I missed anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from purchase object `purchase.getPurchaseToken()`
inside of `onPurchasesUpdated()` method. tokens are generated when purchase is successful.

related doc:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#launch

Comment: Is it for a monthly subscription or regular one time selling?